# Progress Dialog not dismissing

Tags: android, progressdialog

In below code showing progress dialog with 5 second delay. After 5 second want to dismiss the dialog, but not happening in the below.

Can any one please help me where I made the mistake?

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) 
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
       // You don't need anything here
       dialog= ProgressDialog.show(SchedulerActivity.this,"Delay", "Please wait...."+ millisUntilFinished/1000 + " Second(s)",true);
    }

    public void onFinish() 
    {
       dialog.dismiss();
    }

 }.start();
```

Comment: are you sure that onFinish() os triggered?

Comment: [ProgressDialog is deprecated in API level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

`dialog= ProgressDialog.show(SchedulerActivity.this,"Delay", "Please wait...."+ millisUntilFinished/1000 + " Second(s)",true);`

in side `onTick()` method.

it will create new progress dialog instance at every tick. It might cause issue in your function and your dialog will not dismiss in this case.

Please try with below code

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DynamicView.this);
dialog.setTitle("Delay");
dialog.setMessage("Please wait...." + 5000 / 1000 + " Second(s)");
dialog.setIndeterminate(true);

new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // You don't need anything here
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...." + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " Second(s)");

        if (!dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.show();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}.start();
```

This code will works same as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assign value of Progress Dialog to dialog variable. Create Progress Dialog object and set title to it as below.

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
pd.setMessage("what ever message you like");
pd.show();
```

in `onFinish()` please call `pd.dismiss();`

Please set the message in `onTick` method and show progress dialog in this method if progress dialog is not already shown.

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) 
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
       // You don't need anything here
       pd.setMessage("what ever message you like");
        if (!pd.isShowing())
            pd.show();
    }

    public void onFinish() 
    {
       pd.dismiss();
    }

 }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

on tick is calling multiple time that's why your dialog is not closing

implement this

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // You don't need anything here
                if(!dialog.isShowing())
                {
                    dialog= ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"Delay", "Please wait...."+ millisUntilFinished/1000 + " Second(s)",true);
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
```